# Can I create report with filtered custom field values?

Tags: reports, custom-reports

When I create reports, they list either Contacts, Contributions, Activities or similar. Is it possible to list Custom Field entries?

For example, I have a TAB with custom fields. I'd like to get a list of entries that have PARAMETER X with corresponding DATA value from multiple contacts, while not listing Y.

Alternatively, I'd like to get ALL of these **Custom Field entries** from multiple contacts (including contact name), not just the names of contacts that contain these Custom Fields entries.

Is that possible? If not via reports, maybe somehow else?
[image]

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out, I can do it easily with CiviCRM Constituent Summary report. (**Class used: CRM_Report_Form_Contact_Summary**)

I just need to enable to show all necessary custom fields and it returns exactly the table needed.

Comment: excellent - also perhaps worth mentioning that from memory, if  a Custom Field is not set to be Searchable, then it won't be available for the Reports either

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal CMS than you can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to create report.